# Full-Screen-Transculent mode shows empty status bar which should be hidden

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, statusbar

As you can see in the picture, there is a black bar on the top.
Has anybody a idea to *hide* it?

**styles.xml** (default)

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme"></style>
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"></style>
    <style name="AppBaseTheme.Transculent" parent="@style/Theme.Holo.Light.Transculent"></style>
    <style name="Theme.Holo.Light.Transculent" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar.Transculent" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

[image: shows what title describes]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
    <style name="MyTranslucentStatusTheme">
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    </style>
```

This would need to go in values-v19/styles. Also check out https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html!